# Scala 2.8.0 problems on Windows 7

Tags: scala, windows-7, scala-2.8

I installed scala 2.8.0 last night and I seem to be having some issues getting it running. If I type scala at the command prompt it comes up with the following:

```
> scala
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: scala.collection.mutable.ListBuffer.toList()Lscala/collection/immutable/List;
        at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toList(TraversableOnce.scala:399)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps.toList(ArrayOps.scala:34)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner$.main(MainGenericRunner.scala:33)
        at scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner.main(MainGenericRunner.scala)
```

Anyone have any ideas? I'm on Windows 7 professional, with Oracle JRE 1.6.0_21

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this problem occurred because I put the sbt-launch.jar in the lib directory for my scala installation. Once I moved it into another directory scala worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the `SCALA_HOME` environment variable to point to the correct directory?

Comment: It's set to c:\scala, which is the top level directory. It's got bin, doc, lib, meta, misc & src directories in it. I'm guessing this is pointing to the right place?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have an older version installed?  If that's still on your path then it may be causing problems...

**EDIT**

Can you paste the contents of your PATH and CLASSPATH environment variables?  Perhaps using pastie or pastebin if they're on the large side.

You should also update to Java 1.6.0_22 if at all possible, due to this bug which was present in update 21: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=6969236

Comment: I have sbt installed. Will that affect anything?

Comment: SBT will download and use its own copy of scala-compiler and scala-library.  So if SBT works but running "raw" scalac doesn't, then there's a good chance you have problems with your path.